# inherited class AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: automapper

I am new at automapper and it is a very good stuff easy to use, but now I have a problem with it. Trying to convert my derived class to base and it gives me

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
>
> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: ClientEventDb -> EventId
>         Database.ClientEventDb -> EventId
>
> Destination path: ClientEvent
>
> Source value:
>
> Event:Login

Automapper wants to convert ClientEventDb to EventId? I don't understand why. EventId is an enum...

Please help me I have run out of ideas.

Here is the code which I run:

```
ClientEventDb[] edbl;
using (var context = new DbEntities())
{
    edbl=context.Events.Take(1000).ToArray();
}
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientEventDb, ClientEvent>();
Console.WriteLine("hello");
return edbl.Select(edb => Mapper.Map<ClientEvent>(edb)).ToArray();
```

Here are my classes

```
   [Table("events", Schema = "public")]
    public class ClientEventDb : ClientEvent
    {
        public ClientEventDb(string userName, EventId happening, object userObject = null)
            : base(userName, happening, userObject)
        {

        }
        public ClientEventDb()
        {

        }
    }

[ProtoContract]
[Table("events", Schema = "public")]
public class ClientEvent : ClientEventBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [Column("username")]
    public string UserName { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [Column("time")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    [Column("data")]
    public byte[] UserObject { get; set; }

    public ClientEvent(string userName,EventId happening, object userObject=null) : base(happening)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        //UserObject = null;
        if (userObject!=null) throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public ClientEvent()
    {

    }
    protected ClientEvent Clone()
    {
        return (ClientEvent)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(ClientEvent))]
public class ClientEventBase
{

    [Column("eventid")]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int EventIdValue { get; set; } //must be public because of entity framework

    [NotMapped]
    public EventId EventId
    {
        get { return (EventId) EventIdValue; }
        set { EventIdValue = (int) value; }
    }

    public ClientEventBase(EventId eventId)
    {
        EventId = eventId;
    }
    public ClientEventBase()
    {

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Event:{0}",EventId);
    }
}

public enum EventId
{
    Login = 1,
    Logout,
    ExitApplication,
}
```

**UPDATE**

bugfix: ClientEvent [Key] attribute moved to id property

Solution was this (thx to stuartd):

```
ClientEventDb[] edbl;
using (var context = new DbEntities())
{
    edbl=context.Events.ToArray();
}
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientEventDb, ClientEvent>().ConstructUsing((ClientEventDb src) => new ClientEvent());
return edbl.Select(Mapper.Map<ClientEvent>).ToArray();
```

Comment: The problem is reproducible from your code, but it took a lot of cleaning up. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are right! Next time I will make it cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `ClientEvent` has two constructors but you have not told AutoMapper which to use.

If you want it to use your constructor with parameters, change your mapping code to this and it will work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientEventDb, ClientEvent>()
      .ConstructUsing(src => new ClientEvent(src.UserName, src.EventId));
```

Or to make AutoMapper use the default constructor:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientEventDb, ClientEvent>()
      .ConstructUsing((ClientEventDb src) => new ClientEvent());
```

Answer (score 4):

AutoMapper is confused as its made to map between similar properties in different classes, you are using it incorrectly - you just need to go from the derived class to the base which does not require AutoMapper. You could use this to do what you need....

```
ClientEventDb[] edbl;
using (var context = new DbEntities())
{
    edbl=context.Events.Take(1000).ToArray();
}

return edbl.Cast<ClientEvent>().ToList();
```

I'd be looking at why you even feel you need a derived ClientEventDb though - understand we dont have the whole picture here but it seems to do nothing in addition to what the base class already does.

Comment: It certainly looks that way.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! I forget to mention that I am using .net4.0 maybe thats the reason why ConvertAll gives me syntax error if I used it that way.
Good point that ClientEventDb does not add extra to  ClientEvent. The reason is that I would like to make sure that later we can add server only features to the class which is not present in the shared class(ClientEvent)

Comment: @DavidMolnar - sorry - I was at home and couldn't test what I had written last night. I have edited my answer using the linq cast method of converting which will work.

Comment: Could be a good solution but not this time. As you mentioned I have not give you the full vision. I am using Serializer(protobuf) to push this packet throught the network. When I give the casted object to the serializer it gives me:
'Unexpected sub-type: ClientEventDb'
Serializer always tries to serialize the specific "real" type of the object. ClientEventDb is not serializable because I don't want to give that class visible for Client application. Thats why I need AutoMapper.